# How do I connect these clips?

Tags: connector, identification

I bought a couple of clips like this . Does anyone know how to connect them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To attach them to a wire before initial use pull out the plug on the top, feed a wire through the hole in the plug, solder the wire to the metal part on the other piece, then push the plug back into place.

To attach them to a device simply push on the plug until the metal hook extends from the end, hook it onto the device, then release the plug.

Comment: Ah, I have to solder them. I didnt know that. I thought it was a push fit

Comment: Solder them quickly with the minimum amount of heat required to get a good joint. The plastic typically used in these clips melts *very* easily. Commercially-assembled ones are often crimped with a small ferrule rather than soldered.